# How to change field style in the sanity io user interface?

Tags: content-management-system, sanity, headless-cms

How can I change a style of a component easy? I just want limit a text-field height in a sanity user inerface. 
[image]
It is uncomfortable to scroll all the text every time. Where can I write something like that:

```css
{
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot provided in the question, it seems you're using [rexxars markdown plugin](https://github.com/rexxars/sanity-plugin-markdown) for Sanity. When defining the markdown field in your schema, you have some [options](https://github.com/rexxars/sanity-plugin-markdown#options) to choose from. I'm guessing what you want is a low minimum number of rows and to disable auto grow? E.g.:

```js
export default {
  name: 'blogPost',
  title: 'Blog Post',
  type: 'document',
  fields: [
    // ... other blogPost fields 
    {
      name: 'body',
      title: 'Body',
      type: 'markdown',
      options: {
        minRows: 10,
        autoGrow: false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If the options you need aren't available, try creating an [issue](https://github.com/rexxars/sanity-plugin-markdown/issues) or submit a pull request, proposing the change you need?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package). Just followed instructions in the package.